# Write array to text file with max number of elements in each file

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't think this is a dup though there are similar named Questions.
Since Edge is replacing IE and therefore no more Active-X calls from JavaScript so I'm using file drops.

Upon Edit, I will explain my problem in more detail.
I wrote a mapping program for my client that used to use TWebBrowser and IE.  IE allowed ActiveX, which I use extensively.  This is a core app for their business!!

My web page allows the user to block off an area of the map I have drawn for the.  The Map has contiguous polygons which they can block off and save to the database.
I used to "machine gun" each QtrMinute into the database one at a time via ActiveX I wrote.  With that gone. I need another way to save their selection.  So I wrote a filedrop system that saves the selected QtrMins to a text file that I pick up in Delphi and write to the DB.  It is actually quite fast since I send them as a array.

My problem is that I can only block about 300 QtrMinutes and save.  If I block more, nothing happens.  Not exception is thrown.  It just dows not respond.  It used to work on thousands, at a pop(though I was processing them one at a time, which is not practical using a file drop).

I am using an Edge browser made from WebView4Delphi. I am quite certain that the problem is in the Javascript since the ICoreWebView2DownloadStartingEvent is never hit.

I have observed that when I block off Too Many Qtrminutes and try to save As a Text file and it does not respond, that going back to a small one, i.e. a few hundred, does not work.  It is as if a silent exception was thrown that is still not handled.

I apologize for the complexity but this is the hand I've have been dealt.

Also, I am trying to embed some exception handling or alerts in the "saveTextAsFile" function.  It never appears!?

JS is not my core language so what I have written is pretty primative.  I left out my attempt for fear it would only confuse the question.

```
function SaveQtrMin() {
    savedQtrMinutes='';
    for (var m in qtrArray) {

        savedQtrMinutes =savedQtrMinutes + qtrArray[m].qtrMinute+'\n'
    }

    try {
    saveTextAsFile('FileNameToSave','SaveQtrMinutes'+'\n'+ savedQtrMinutes);
    } catch(exc){
    alert('savedQtrMinutes failed');
    }

}
```

calls the function

```
    function saveTextAsFile( fileNameToSaveAs, textToWrite)
{
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

qtrArray can often have 2000 elements but I want to write it to a text file in 500 elements blocks max. The elements are simply 8 character labels.

> Therefore, I want to put the first 500 in the accumulator
> "savedQtrMinutes", call the function "saveTextAsFile" and then go back
> and get the next 500, until all are written.

I originally hoped that sending them out in smaller blocks would work, but I am not so sure.
The core question remains:
Why can I save a small number of QtrMinutes to a file but not a larger number.  Not exception is thrown.  It just does nothing?  But once it fails, I am not even able to send a small block unless I restart the app.

Answer (score 1):

use `.slice(start, end)` to select array range, for  cross browser `.createObjectURL` use `window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;`

```js
var qtrArray = Array.from(Array(20), (_, i) => i + 1);

SaveQtrMin()

function SaveQtrMin() {
    var start = 0,
        end = 5,
        savedQtrMinutes;
    while (end <= qtrArray.length) {
        savedQtrMinutes = qtrArray.slice(start, end).join("\n")
        saveTextAsFile('FileNameToSave', 'SaveQtrMinutes' + '\n' + savedQtrMinutes);
        console.log('Part:\n', savedQtrMinutes)
        start += 5;
        end += 5;
    }
}

function saveTextAsFile(fileNameToSaveAs, textToWrite) {
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
        type: 'text/plain'
    });
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

note: you have to allow website permission to download multiple file